# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo returns plain text result

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I want to send GetFeatureInfo request to my GeoServer and get response as JSON.

My query string parameters are like this:

- request:GetFeatureInfo
- service:WMS
- info_format:application/json
- exceptions:text/javascript
- version:1.1.0
- ...
- ...

But my response comes like this:

```
Results for FeatureType 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/App:line':
--------------------------------------------
gid = 590545
geom = ...
name = ...
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to get response as JSON result.

I set `exceptions:application/json` but it did not work.

This was working before, but I moved GeoServer to another server. I think some settings are not set in a config file about JSON response.

My GetCapabilities response is like this:

```
  <GetFeatureInfo>
    <Format>text/plain</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
    <Format>text/html</Format>
    <Format>text/javascript</Format>
    <Format>application/json</Format>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is APP:line some application schema layer? To show that json infoformat can work, try

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp%3Astates&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-117.1142578125%2C32.8271484375%2C-108.2373046875%2C41.7041015625

Comment: "App" stands for workspace, "line" is layer name

Comment: Do you get json response from your own GeoServer with the above request if you change the server address to localhost:8080?

Comment: I fixed solution as change my parameter names to upper case. Lower case named info_format does not work. Why?

Comment: Maybe a bug. In WMS standard the keys are not case-sensitive while the values are. Which GeoServer versions you run on your old and new servers?

Comment: Geoserver version is 2.5.1

Comment: Lower case `info_format` works with the geo-solutions demo server. If there was a bug in 2.5.1 it will not be fixed. Current versions are 2.11 and 2.12.